# UISplitviewController with sliding menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad, sliding

My split view controller is set as the root view controller in my app delegate.
I need to slide my split view to the right (master and detail view) about 200px, while sliding in a menu view from left to right (left of the split view) at the same time which has a width of 200px. So my split view would slide off the main view while the menu view appears. Ive tried adding a subview to UIWindow which I beleive is not the right way to do it. Ive tried adding my menuViewController to my split view controllers' master view controller. But it doesnt seem to work. Help please!!!